# Analysis of longitudinal data with very few points

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to analyse some data I've recently gotten my hands on, but I'm not entirely sure which model to use. One suggestion has been a Mixed Model, Repeated Measurements ANOVA, but I'm not sure if that such kind of model can answer the questions of interest.

**The data**:
Two individual persons (A and B) have had a lot of different values (V1, V2, V3, ..., Vn) measured four times (At T0, T1, T2 and T3) - The spacing between times differs.

The different values have been grouped into categories (C1, C2, C3, ..., Cn). One value may belong to none, one or multiple categories. Each of the categories have a continuos value (Response_C1,Response_C1, ..., Response_Cn), which is the sum of the measured values belonging to that category.

In addition to this, person B was given a drug at T1.

What I would like to investigate now, is:

1. Is there any observable effect after administering the drug
2. On which categories did the drug have an effect
3. If there is an effct on a category, what is the effect size
4. How does the effect vary over time
5. If there is an effect, is the effect observed from the drug at T1 still persistant at T3

I realise one of the major pitfalls is the lack of both time points and samples, but it would be appreciated if you could suggest any articles/methods for this type of analysis.

**What I have tried so far** is just Repeated Measurements ANOVA, using R:

```r
    test.aov <- aov(Response_C ~ Category * Timepoint * Treatment + 
                    Error(Sample), data=df)
```

But I am not sure that the model is correct, neither am I sure that it actually answers my questions, even if I try to model it as a mixed model.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed

**Edit 1:** After doing some more reading, it seems a Generalised Linear Model with a negative binomial distribution (since this kind of data is usually over-dispersed) might be better suited for this kind of data, but I'm still not sure if such a model would answer the questions. Potentially I could fit a model to each individual category, but that would inflate the Type-I error I guess, and so we would need to correct for multiple testing.

**Edit 2:** Some more reading, and I thought the `lme4` R package would be a good way to fit a Linear mixed model to my data, and just do individual comparisons of each category. Here's the model I tried to fit:

```
lm1 <- lmer(Response ~ Treatment * Timepoint + (1|Subject), data=my_data)
```

First off, I'm not sure whether Timepoint should be a factorial or a numerical value. As I mentioned, timepoints are not evenly distributed (To be precise, I have for time 0, 2days, 14 days, 90days), however, the design is balanced. If I enter the Timepoints as a numerical value, I don't get any estimate of what the value is at any given Timepoint, but just some numbers for Correlation of fixed effects, which I can't really use for anything. On the other hand, if I enter the Timepoints as factors, I do get an estimated value for the effect at each timepoint, but I'm not too sure how certain or reliable this value is.

Comment: While I completely agree that conceptually `Subject` should be a random effect, given you have only two instances I am a bit worried about the numerical efficiency of what you'll be doing. Maybe using it a fixed effect (ie. as an interaction) will not be unreasonable.

Comment: I do not believe your number of data-points to be the problem rather than your number of subjects in order to initiate an Mix.Model. Check Yao et al. 2004 on *Functional Data Analysis for Sparse Longitudinal Data*, it might be a helpful reference. I would propose using their methodology/code (PACE - they have a Matlab package) to do PCA on your data and then try modelling each PC score family independently. A bit of a long-shot but could possibly work fine as (hopefully) there will be a *slope*-like FPC that is influenced significantly by your Treatment variable.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, thanks. The only problem is that PACE is only available for Matlab, which I do not have access to. Are you aware if a package exists for R/Python/Perl? I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, sorry. Apparently they had a CRAN package but given it was retracted I would not trust it. In general PACE is a very broad package, you want just the FPCA decomposition as it is presented in the paper I mentioned in Sect. 2.3 (correction: it is a 2005 JASA paper, not 2004). It should not be extremely hard to implement.